# Jest: Disable line return match checking

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have some tests that run on linux and windows and that read a file that contains line return. A simplified version of the test is the following:

```js
describe("Foo bar", () => {
  it("should match content without regarding line return", () => {
    const foo = { content: "foo\nbar" };
    const bar = { content: "foo\r\nbar" };

    expect(foo).toMatchObject(bar);
  });
});
```

This one failed because `\n` != `\r\n`. So is there an easy way to tell jest to ignore such cases without having to directly manipulate the strings?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this directly in jest without creating a custom matcher, so if you decide to directly manipulate the strings, you can use something like [normalize-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-newline).

```js
import normalizeNewline from 'normalize-newline';
describe("Foo bar", () => {
  it("should match content without regarding line return", () => {
    const foo = { content: normalizeNewline("foo\nbar") };
    const bar = { content: normalizeNewline("foo\r\nbar") };

    expect(foo).toMatchObject(bar);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the int but I hoped there was another way.